# Dynamics AX POS retail SDK missing DLLs

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have started working on Dynamics AX POS. I have loaded the retail SDK into Visual Studio and I am facing some dll missing error like type or namespace "transaction" does not exist. what is the possible solution and where can I find these DLLs. 
I am absolutely new to this technology

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/189496) in Dynamics AX community.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help section of stack overflow. Your question does not provide enough information to answer it. At the very least consider copying the information you gave in the AX community forum to this question.